# Is there a maximum value of sample for Anti Aliasing in Unity?

Tags: unity, antialiasing, multisampling

In Quality settings, there is Antialiasing option with 2~8x sample range. I can change the sample by script like this:

```
QualitySettings.antiAliasing = myAAValue;
```

However is there a maximum value? In Unity Editor, minimum is 2 and maximum is 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 is the maximum supported value. See the [Unity Manual on the AntiAliasing option](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html):

> AntiAliasing - This sets the level of antialiasing that will be used.
>   The options are 2x, 4x and 8x multi-sampling.

Note that when setting via script, `antiAliasing` is an int, so if you set a higher unsupported value it should default to the highest supported number less than the indicated number. See Unity's [`QualitySettings.antialising` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-antiAliasing.html) that mentions this behavior:

> **QualitySettings.antiAliasing**
>
> `public static int antiAliasing;`
>
> Set The AA Filtering option.
>
> Anti-aliasing value indicates the number of samples per pixel. If
>   unsupported by the hardware or rendering API, the greatest supported
>   number of samples less than the indicated number is used.